# calling CUDA library functions

Tags: fourier-analysis, cudalink

Mathematica has some predefined CUDA functions, like CUDAMap, CUDAFourier, etc. My question is how can one call functions which are part of CUDA library but not part of predefined Mathematica functions? For example, CUDA 6.0 has a large Math library; so if I am to call cuFFT from that library instead of using CUDAFourier, how would I go about doing this? Do I have to write a C code which calls the cuda library function and then call the c function from Mathematica. That seems too round about way of doing something. I could not quite find it in the documentation. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*CUDALink* allows you to write custom kernels but unfortunately it doesn't allow to use its `CUDAMemory` in other functions. I found two methods to deal with it.

**Documented method**

You can use *LibraryLink* and call CUDA functions as in a regular CUDA program. For example, you can write something like [fourier.cu](http://pastebin.com/ghuvNE5F). Then you can compile it and load "fourier_single" or "fourier" depending on your GPU architecture

```
SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[];
Needs["CUDALink`"]
CreateLibrary[{"fourier.cu"}, "libfourier", 
  "Compiler" -> NVCCCompiler, "Libraries" -> "cufft"];
AppendTo[$LibraryPath, NotebookDirectory[]];
fourier = LibraryFunctionLoad["libfourier", "fourier", {{_Complex, 1}}, {_Complex, 1}];
```

I don't consider this method in details because it has a big disadvantage: you have to copy your data to GPU and backward every time you call the function.

**Undocumented method**

Let us look through system files of *Mathematica*. There are brilliant examples in `$InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/Links/CUDALink/CSource/`! They use undocumented *MathematicaGPULibrary* (WGL). This library allows to interact directly with `CUDAMemory` by its ID. I adapted these examples to demonstrate the usage of 1D single precision CUFFT (say, "fourier.cu" in the same directory  as the notebook)

```c
#include    <wgl.h>
#include    <wgl_cuda_runtime.h>

#define wglState                            (wglData->state)
#define wglErr                                (wglData->getError(wglData))
#define WGL_SuccessQ                        (wglErr->code == WGL_Success)
#define WGL_FailQ                            (!WGL_SuccessQ)
#define WGL_Type_RealQ(mem)                    ((mem)->type == WGL_Real_t)

#define WGL_SAFE_CALL(stmt, jmp)            stmt; if (WGL_FailQ) { goto jmp; }

WolframGPULibraryData wglData = NULL;

static int iFourier(WGL_Memory_t input, WGL_Memory_t output) {
    int err;

    err = LIBRARY_FUNCTION_ERROR;

    if (input->type != output->type) {
        return LIBRARY_TYPE_ERROR;
    } else if (input->flattenedLength != output->flattenedLength) {
        return LIBRARY_DIMENSION_ERROR;
    }

    WGL_SAFE_CALL(CUDA_Runtime_setMemoryAsInput(wglState, input, wglErr), cleanup);
    WGL_SAFE_CALL(CUDA_Runtime_setMemoryAsOutput(wglState, output, wglErr), cleanup);

    cufftHandle plan;
    cufftPlan1d(&plan, input->flattenedLength, CUFFT_C2C, 1);

    cufftExecC2C(
        plan, 
        (cufftComplex *)CUDA_Runtime_getDeviceMemoryAsComplexFloat(input), 
        (cufftComplex *)CUDA_Runtime_getDeviceMemoryAsComplexFloat(output), 
        CUFFT_INVERSE
    );
    cufftDestroy(plan);


    err = LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;

cleanup:
    if (WGL_SuccessQ) {
        CUDA_Runtime_setMemoryAsValidOutput(wglState, output, wglErr);
    } else {
        CUDA_Runtime_setMemoryAsInvalidOutput(wglState, output, wglErr);
    }
    CUDA_Runtime_unsetMemoryAsInput(wglState, input, wglErr);
    if (WGL_SuccessQ && err == LIBRARY_NO_ERROR) {
        return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
    } else {
        return LIBRARY_FUNCTION_ERROR;
    }
}

EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT int oFourier(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument * Args, MArgument Res) {
    WGL_Memory_t input, output;
    mint inputId, outputId;
    int err = LIBRARY_FUNCTION_ERROR;

    inputId                     = MArgument_getInteger(Args[0]);
    outputId                     = MArgument_getInteger(Args[1]);

    WGL_SAFE_CALL(wglData->setWolframLibraryData(wglData, libData), cleanup);

    WGL_SAFE_CALL(input = wglData->findMemory(wglData, inputId), cleanup);
    WGL_SAFE_CALL(output = wglData->findMemory(wglData, outputId), cleanup);

    err = iFourier(input, output);

cleanup:    
    return err;
}

EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT int WolframGPULibrary_initialize(WolframGPULibraryData wglData0) {
    wglData = wglData0;
    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}

EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT int WolframLibrary_initialize(WolframLibraryData libData) {
   return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}

EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT void WolframLibrary_uninitialize( ) {
   return;
}
```

Let's go back to *Mathematica* and compile the source and load the function

```
SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[];
Needs["CUDALink`"]
CreateLibrary[{"fourier.cu"}, "libfourier.so", 
  "TargetDirectory" -> ".", "Compiler" -> NVCCCompiler, 
  "Defines" -> "CONFIG_USE_CUDA", 
  "Libraries" -> FileNameJoin@{$CUDALinkLibraryPath, "libCUDALink_Single.so"}];

fourier = 
  CUDAFunctionLoad[{FileNameJoin@{NotebookDirectory[], 
      "libfourier.so"}}, 
   "oFourier", {{_Integer, "Input"}, {_Integer, "Output"}}, 256, 
   TargetPrecision -> "Single"];
```

Notes:

- `CONFIG_USE_CUDA` flag is necessary for using CUDA in WGL. Another flag is `CONFIG_USE_OPENCL`.
- Initialization of WGL fails without `"Libraries" -> FileNameJoin@{$CUDALinkLibraryPath, "libCUDALink_Single.so"}`. However everything will work if you evaluate any built-in `CUDA*` function before.
- For double precision change `Single` to `Double`, `Float` to `Double`, `C2C` to `Z2Z` and `cufftComplex` to `cufftDoubleComplex` everywhere above and below.
- `CUFFT_INVERSE` corresponds to forward `Fourier` with `FourierParameters -> {1, 1}`.
- Input and output is `_Integer` because they transfer integer IDs, not the data itself.
- Headers of WGL are located in `` GPUTools`Internal`$GPUToolsSystemResourcesPath ``
- Built-in functions like `CUDAFourier` are loaded in `$CUDALinkPath/CUDALink.m`. It can be used as an example of loading WGL functions.

Tests (change `2^24` to an appropriate value if you don't have enough GPU memory):

```
x = RandomComplex[{-1 - I, 1 + I}, 2^24];
ByteCount[x]
(* 268435600 *)

f1 = Fourier[x]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.404416, Null} *)

gx = CUDAMemoryLoad[x, TargetPrecision -> "Single"]
gf = CUDAMemoryAllocate[Complex, Length[x], TargetPrecision -> "Single"]
(* CUDAMemory["<587248096>", "ComplexFloat"] *)
(* CUDAMemory["<1373924031>", "ComplexFloat"] *)

fourier[gx, gf]; // AbsoluteTiming
f2 = CUDAMemoryGet@gf/Sqrt@Length@x;
Norm[f2 - f1]/Norm[f1]
(* {0.010405, Null} *)
(* 2.64293*10^-7 *)

CUDAMemoryUnload[gf];
gf = CUDAFourier[gx]; // AbsoluteTiming
f3 = CUDAMemoryGet@gf;
Norm[f3 - f1]/Norm[f1]
(* {0.183712, Null} *)
(* 2.25279*10^-8 *)

CUDAMemoryUnload[gf, gx]
```

It works! I tested it with GTX 560 (2.0 architecture, showed above) and 9600M GT (1.1 architecture without double-precision) on Linux. Both tests show that our `fourier` is much faster then CPU and faster then built-in `CUDAFourier`. On GTX 560 `CUDAFourier` is relatively slow because it uses double precision and I don't know how to switch it to the single precision.

I will appreciate for any tests of WGL on other systems!

Comment: This looks great. CUDALink is broken (again) on my home PC but I'll test it at work on the Quadro 4000 tomorrow.

Comment: I think this is amazing that we can use CUDA libraries directly in LibraryLink. But I don't quite understand how this work. For example, what's so special about CUDA functions that prevent them been called like  ordinary functions in LibraryLink? And why do we need to interact with CUDAMemory object when using CUDA functions such as `cufftExecC2C`? Thanks.

Comment: @xslittlegrass We *can* use LibraryLink like in my first example and call CUDA functions without CUDAMemory. However the bandwidth between CPU and GPU is very small so we have to avoid unnecessary copying to/from GPU. It is difficult to do without WGL because we cannot share GPU memory between different libraries and build-in routines (like CUDADot).

Comment: @ybeltukov I guess I don't understand why the second approach avoids copying data from CPU to GPU. It looks like in the second example, `gx` is copied from CPU, is that right? As I understand, in both cases, we need to copy data from CPU to GPU, and after the computation on GPU finished, we need to copy data back. But why is the second approach faster?

Comment: @xslittlegrass You are right, in this simple example the speed is the same. However, in real projects with multiple evaluation of function(s) you can permanently store a main data in the GPU memory.

Comment: @ybeltukov, I have tried your example code in my windows mathematica 10.4 and cuda paclet 10.2.0.3, but it showed link errors. The details list in my question [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111925/calling-cuda-library-functions-using-mathematicagpulibrary-wgl).

Comment: @Simon Woods, did you test the wgl methods on your platform?

Comment: In Mathematica 11 on CenOS 7 I had to omit "Libraries" -> "cufft" from the Create Library command. Including the libraries argument caused LibraryFunctionLoad to fail with "could not load function ... from ..." Hope that helps someone facing the same issue.