# How to use SparseArray in CUDA?

Tags: sparse-arrays, cudalink

Sparse arrays are widely used in many scientific applications where memory and time are strictly limited. For a considerable speedup one can use CUDA. Since *Mathematica* 8  we can conveniently use CUDA directly from *Mathematica*. However we can use only dense matrices. Neither version 9 nor version 10 did not add CUDA sparse arrays. However, CUSPARSE library of GPU-accelerated sparse matrix routines was introduced in [CUDA Toolkit 3.2](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-32-downloads), November 2010, i.e. 4 years ago! Is it possible to use CUSPARSE directly from *Mathematica* now?

It is not a simple problem. On the one hand CUDALink doesn't allow you to use routines from the external libraries. On the other hand LibraryLink doesn't allow you to use `CUDAMemory` and its reference to GPU memory.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, it is possible! There is a WorframGPULibrary (WGL), which I discover [recently](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/60261/4678). It is undocumented, however there are beautiful examples in

```
$InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/Links/CUDALink/CSource/
```

It is similar to LibraryLink, but allows `CUDAMemory` as an argument. I wrote the code below to call main CUSPARSE routines directly from *Mathematica*

$$
C := \alpha (AB)^T + \beta C
$$

or

$$
c := \alpha Ab + \beta c.
$$

Where $A$ is a sparse matrix, $B$ and $C$ are dense matrices, $b$ and $c$ are dense vectors. The motivation of transposition is to improve the memory access and increase CUDA performance (approximately twice). You can always quickly transpose input and output as you want.

## Features

- Matrix-matrix and matrix-vector operations.
- Single and double precision.
- Real or complex values.
- Most popular [CSR](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#compressed-sparse-row-format-csr) and [BSR](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#block-compressed-sparse-row-format-bsr) formats of sparse arrays.
- Up to 30x speedup.

## Source

There is almost nothing interesting, just calling appropriate CUSPARSE routines (`sparse.cu`):

```c
#include    <wgl.h>
#include    <wgl_cuda_runtime.h>

#define wglState                            (wglData->state)
#define wglErr                              (wglData->getError(wglData))
#define WGL_SuccessQ                        (wglErr->code == WGL_Success)
#define WGL_FailQ                           (!WGL_SuccessQ)
#define WGL_Type_RealQ(mem)                 ((mem)->type == WGL_Real_t)

#define WGL_SAFE_CALL(stmt, jmp)            stmt; if (WGL_FailQ) { goto jmp; }

#define TRA CUSPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE
#define TRB CUSPARSE_OPERATION_TRANSPOSE
#define BDR CUSPARSE_DIRECTION_ROW

#define GET(type, ptr)  CUDA_Runtime_getDeviceMemoryAs##type(ptr)

#define CSRMM(c, type)  cusparse##c##csrmm2(handle, TRA, TRB, m, n, k, nnzb, \
                                            &alpha##c, descrA, GET(type, A_val), \
                                            GET(Integer, A_ptr), GET(Integer, A_ind), \
                                            GET(type, B), n, &beta##c, GET(type, C), m)

#define CSRMV(c, type)  cusparse##c##csrmv(handle, TRA, m, k, nnzb, \
                                            &alpha##c, descrA, GET(type, A_val), \
                                            GET(Integer, A_ptr), GET(Integer, A_ind), \
                                            GET(type, B), &beta##c, GET(type, C))

#if CUDA_VERSION >= 6050

#define BSRMM(c, type)  cusparse##c##bsrmm(handle, BDR, TRA, TRB, m/bs, n, k/bs, nnzb, \
                                            &alpha##c, descrA, GET(type, A_val), \
                                            GET(Integer, A_ptr), GET(Integer, A_ind), bs, \
                                            GET(type, B), n, &beta##c, GET(type, C), m)

#else
#define BSRMM(c, type)  CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS; return LIBRARY_VERSION_ERROR;  // CUDA 6.5 or later is required for bsrmm
#endif

#define BSRMV(c, type)  cusparse##c##bsrmv(handle, BDR, TRA, m/bs, k/bs, nnzb, \
                                            &alpha##c, descrA, GET(type, A_val), \
                                            GET(Integer, A_ptr), GET(Integer, A_ind), bs, \
                                            GET(type, B), &beta##c, GET(type, C))

#define SRM(c, type)    if (r==2) { \
                            if (bs==1) ret = CSRMM(c, type); \
                            else  ret = BSRMM(c, type); \
                        } else { \
                            if (bs==1) ret = CSRMV(c, type); \
                            else  ret = BSRMV(c, type); \
                        }  



WolframGPULibraryData wglData = NULL;

EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT int osrmm(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument * Args, MArgument Res) {
    int err = LIBRARY_FUNCTION_ERROR;
    WGL_Memory_t A_val, A_ptr, A_ind, B, C;
    int r, m, n, k, nnzb, bs;

    cusparseHandle_t handle = 0;
    cusparseMatDescr_t descrA = 0;
    cusparseStatus_t ret;

    float alphaS, betaS;
    double alphaD, betaD;
    cuComplex alphaC, betaC;
    cuDoubleComplex alphaZ, betaZ;

    WGL_SAFE_CALL(wglData->setWolframLibraryData(wglData, libData), cleanup);

    WGL_SAFE_CALL(A_val = wglData->findMemory(wglData,MArgument_getInteger(Args[0])), cleanup);
    WGL_SAFE_CALL(A_ptr = wglData->findMemory(wglData,MArgument_getInteger(Args[1])), cleanup);
    WGL_SAFE_CALL(A_ind = wglData->findMemory(wglData,MArgument_getInteger(Args[2])), cleanup);

    m = MArgument_getInteger(Args[3]);
    k = MArgument_getInteger(Args[4]);
    nnzb = A_ind->flattenedLength;
    bs = sqrt(A_val->flattenedLength/nnzb);

    WGL_SAFE_CALL(B = wglData->findMemory(wglData, MArgument_getInteger(Args[5])), cleanup);
    WGL_SAFE_CALL(C = wglData->findMemory(wglData, MArgument_getInteger(Args[6])), cleanup);

    if ((A_val->type != B->type)||(B->type != C->type)||(A_val->type != C->type)) {
        return LIBRARY_TYPE_ERROR;
    }

    r = B->rank;
    if ((r != C->rank)||(r > 2)) return LIBRARY_DIMENSION_ERROR;
    if (r == 2) {
        n = B->dimensions[1];
        if ((m != C->dimensions[1])||(n != C->dimensions[0])||(k != B->dimensions[0]))
            return LIBRARY_DIMENSION_ERROR;
    } else if ((m != C->flattenedLength)||(k != B->flattenedLength))
        return LIBRARY_DIMENSION_ERROR;

    WGL_SAFE_CALL(CUDA_Runtime_setMemoryAsInput(wglState, A_val, wglErr), cleanup);
    WGL_SAFE_CALL(CUDA_Runtime_setMemoryAsInput(wglState, A_ptr, wglErr), cleanup);
    WGL_SAFE_CALL(CUDA_Runtime_setMemoryAsInput(wglState, A_ind, wglErr), cleanup);
    WGL_SAFE_CALL(CUDA_Runtime_setMemoryAsInput(wglState, B,     wglErr), cleanup);
    WGL_SAFE_CALL(CUDA_Runtime_setMemoryAsInputOutput(wglState, C, wglErr), cleanup);

    cusparseCreate(&handle);
    cusparseCreateMatDescr(&descrA);

    switch(A_val->type)
    {
        case WGL_Type_Float:
            alphaS = MArgument_getReal(Args[7]);
            betaS = MArgument_getReal(Args[9]);
            SRM(S, Float)
            break;
        case WGL_Type_Double:
            alphaD = MArgument_getReal(Args[7]);
            betaD = MArgument_getReal(Args[9]);
            SRM(D, Double);
            break;
        case WGL_Type_ComplexFloat:
            alphaC.x = MArgument_getReal(Args[7]);
            alphaC.y = MArgument_getReal(Args[8]);
            betaC.x = MArgument_getReal(Args[9]);
            betaC.y = MArgument_getReal(Args[10]);
            SRM(C, ComplexFloat);
            break;
        case WGL_Type_ComplexDouble:
            alphaZ.x = MArgument_getReal(Args[7]);
            alphaZ.y = MArgument_getReal(Args[8]);
            betaZ.x = MArgument_getReal(Args[9]);
            betaZ.y = MArgument_getReal(Args[10]);
            SRM(Z, ComplexDouble);
            break;
    }

    cusparseDestroyMatDescr(descrA);
    cusparseDestroy(handle);

    err = LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;

cleanup:
    if (WGL_SuccessQ) {
        CUDA_Runtime_setMemoryAsValidInputOutput(wglState, C, wglErr);
    } else {
        CUDA_Runtime_setMemoryAsInvalidInputOutput(wglState, C, wglErr);
    }
    CUDA_Runtime_unsetMemoryAsInput(wglState, A_val, wglErr);
    CUDA_Runtime_unsetMemoryAsInput(wglState, A_ptr, wglErr);
    CUDA_Runtime_unsetMemoryAsInput(wglState, A_ind, wglErr);
    CUDA_Runtime_unsetMemoryAsInput(wglState, B, wglErr);
    if (WGL_SuccessQ && err == LIBRARY_NO_ERROR && ret == CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS) {
        return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
    } else {
        return LIBRARY_FUNCTION_ERROR;
    }
}

EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT int WolframGPULibrary_initialize(WolframGPULibraryData wglData0) {
    wglData = wglData0;
    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}

EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT int WolframLibrary_initialize(WolframLibraryData libData) {
   return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}

EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT void WolframLibrary_uninitialize( ) {
   return;
}
```

Notes:

- Data storage in *Mathematica* and CUSPARSE are different: row-major and column-major respectively. So you have to keep in mind a virtual transposition of all dense matrices.
- `#define TRB CUSPARSE_OPERATION_TRANSPOSE` means: apply additional virtual transposition to the matrix $B$ to increase memory access. It requires CUDA architecture 2.0 or later. You can switch it to `#define TRB CUSPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE` and perform $C := \alpha (AB^T)^T + \beta C$.
- CUDA 6.5 or later is required for [bsrmm](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#cusparse-lt-t-gt-bsrmm) (matrix-matrix multiplication with BSR format).

## Compilation

Now you can try to compile this code. I say "try" because the proper compilation even more difficult then writing the code. I use *Mathematica* 10 under Linux with the system installation of CUDA 6.5. My magic code:

```
$HistoryLength = 0;
SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[];
Needs["CUDALink`"];
Off[OptionValue::nodef];
CreateLibrary[{"sparse.cu"}, "libsparse.so",
    "Compiler" -> NVCCCompiler,
    "CUDAArchitecture" -> 
     CUDALink`Private`getCUDAArchitecture /@ Range@Length@CUDAInformation[],
    "CompilerInstallation" -> "/opt/cuda/bin",
    "TargetDirectory" -> ".",
    "Defines" -> {"CONFIG_USE_CUDA", "CONFIG_USE_CUSPARSE", 
      If[#, "CONFIG_USE_DOUBLE_PRECISION", ## &[]]},
    "LibraryDirectories" -> $CUDALinkLibraryPath,
    "Libraries" -> {If[#, "CUDALink_Double", "CUDALink_Single"], cusparse"},
    "ShellCommandFunction" -> Print,
    "ShellOutputFunction" -> Print] &@
  CUDALink`Internal`SupportsDoublePrecisionQ@$CUDADevice;
```

- `"CUDAArchitecture" -> ...` put current CUDA architecture to `nvcc`. It is necessary because `CreateLibrary` automatically choose all possible architectures including 1.0. However CUDA 6.5 can't compile for architecture 1.0.
- `Off[OptionValue::nodef]` hide meaningless warning about CUDA architecture.
- `"CompilerInstallation" -> ...` location of your `nvcc`.
- `"TargetDirectory" -> "."` create library in the same folder
- `CONFIG_USE_CUSPARSE` includes CUSPARSE headers. This flag is exist in WGL but disabled by default!
- `If[#, "CONFIG_USE_DOUBLE_PRECISION", ## &[]]` turns on `CONFIG_USE_DOUBLE_PRECISION` if your GPU supports double precision. It is necessary for proper type detection.
- `If[#, "CUDALink_Double", "CUDALink_Single"]` is necessary for proper WGL initialization. Also depends on the double precision support.
- `"ShellCommandFunction" -> Print` and `"ShellOutputFunction" -> Print` show full compilation command and output from `nvcc`.

## Loading

Now you can load the library

```
srmm = CUDAFunctionLoad[{FileNameJoin@{NotebookDirectory[], "libsparse.so"}}, 
   "osrmm", {{_Integer, "Input"}, {_Integer, "Input"}, {_Integer, "Input"}, 
    _Integer, _Integer,
    {_Integer, "Input"}, {_Integer, "InputOutput"}, 
    _Real, _Real, _Real, _Real}, {16, 16}];
```

If you compiled the library properly then you will see no errors. There are 10 arguments of the function `srmm`. All `{_Integer, ...}` means `CUDAMemory` because it contains an integer ID.

- 3 `CUDAMemory` arguments for the sparse matrix $A$ in CSR or BSR format.
- 2 integer arguments are the height and the width of the matrix $A$.
- 2 `CUDAMemory` arguments are matrices $B$ and $C$ or vectors $b$ and $c$.
- 4 real arguments for the real and the imaginary part of the $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

## cuSparseArray

Definition of the custom `cuSparseArray`

```
HoldPattern@uncover@SparseArray@s__ := {s};

Options[cuSparseArray] = 
  Append[Options[CUDAMemoryLoad], blockSize -> 1];
cuSparseArray[s_SparseArray, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Module[{bs = OptionValue[blockSize], list},
   cuSparseArray[
      CUDAMemoryCopyToDevice /@ 
       CUDAMemoryLoad @@@ {{list = Identity; Flatten@#4[[3]], 
          FilterRules[{opts}, Options@CUDAMemoryLoad]}, {#4[[2, 1]], 
          "Integer32"}, {Flatten@#4[[2, 2]] - 1, "Integer32"}}, 
      bs #2] & @@ 
    uncover@If[bs > 1, 
      Developer`PartitionMap[list@Normal@# &, s, {bs, bs}], s]];

cuDot[cuSparseArray[{val_, ptr_, ind_}, {h_, w_}], b_CUDAMemory, 
   c_CUDAMemory, α_: 1, β_: 0] := 
  srmm[val, ptr, ind, h, w, b, c, Re@α, Im@α, 
   Re@β, Im@β];

CUDAMemoryUnload@cuSparseArray[a_, _] ^:= CUDAMemoryUnload @@ a;
```

- `SparseArray` is already in CSR format. So we have to `uncover` it and load the data.
- If the option `blockSize` is greater then 1 then `SparseArray` will be splitted by `blockSize*blockSize` blocks and loaded in `BSR` format.
- "Integer32" is necessary for indexes because CUSPARSE use 32-bit integers, not 64-bit integers (at least for my system)

## Example

```
a = N@Flatten[LeviCivitaTensor[4], {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}];
b = RandomReal[1, 16];
c = ConstantArray[0., 16];
ga = cuSparseArray[a];
{gb, gc} = CUDAMemoryLoad /@ {b, c};
cuDot[ga, gb, gc];
CUDAMemoryGet[gc] - a.b
```

> {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}

## Benchmarking

Now we can perform a benchmarking for various data types and structures. I use two types of the distribution of nonzero elements in the sparse matrix $A$: random distribution (`bs = 1`) and clustered distribution (`bs = 16`)

[image]

```
prec = "Single"; (* "Single" or "Double" *)
type = "Real"; (* "Real" or "Complex" *)
bs = 1; (* size of blocks in the sparse array *)
format = "CSR"; (* "CSR" or "BSR", GPU storage format *)
struct = "Vector"; (* "Matrix" or "Vector", multiply by what *)
scale = 2^8; (* change depending on your GPU memory, check ByteCount below *)

rnd = If[type == "Real", RandomReal[1, #] &, 
  RandomComplex[1 + I, #] &];
{m, k, n} = scale 2^{7, 6, 0};
nnz = scale 2^14/bs^2;
a = KroneckerProduct[#, rnd[bs {1, 1}]] &@
   SparseArray[
    Sort@Transpose[RandomInteger[{1, #}, nnz] & /@ ({m, k}/bs)] -> 
     rnd[nnz], {m, k}/bs];
b = rnd@If[struct == "Matrix", {k, n}, k];
c = rnd@If[struct == "Matrix", {n, m}, m];
{α, β} = rnd[2];
repeats = If[struct == "Matrix", 20, 300];
Plus @@ ByteCount /@ {a, b, c}
```

> 66 982 088 (Memory used in bytes)

```
ga = cuSparseArray[a, TargetPrecision -> prec, 
   blockSize -> If[format == "CSR", 1, bs]];
{gb, gc} = 
  CUDAMemoryCopyToDevice@
     CUDAMemoryLoad[#, TargetPrecision -> prec] & /@ {b, c};
First@AbsoluteTiming@
   Do[c = α If[struct == "Matrix", (a.b)\[Transpose], 
        a.b] + β c, {repeats}]/
 First@AbsoluteTiming[
   Do[cuDot[ga, gb, gc, α, β], {repeats}]; 
   c2 = CUDAMemoryGet@gc]
Norm[c2 - c, 1]/Norm[c, 1]
CUDAMemoryUnload /@ {ga, gb, gc};
```

> 2.3152 (Speedup)
>
> 4.31758*10^-6 (Accuracy)

The comprehensive table of benchmarking on my system (GTX 560/Core i7 3820)

[image]

Up to 30x speedup! It's not bad for €125 GPU.

I will appreciate for any tests of WGL and CUSPARSE. Thank you for reading such a long post!

Comment: sorry to send your information again. I have tried your example code [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47702/calling-cuda-library-functions/60261#60261) in my windows mathematica 10.4 and cuda paclet 10.2.0.3, but it showed link errors. The details list in my question [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111925/calling-cuda-library-functions-using-mathematicagpulibrary-wgl).