# Calling CUDA cuFFT

Tags: fourier-analysis, cudalink

Following [ybeltukov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4678/ybeltukov)'s excellent answers (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47702/28113) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/60424/28113)) about how to access the CUDA library functions and interact with Mathematica through CUDAMemory, I tried to compile the code given in [ybeltukov's first post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47702/28113). The reason behind that is that I would like to implement a wave-propagation ODE solver (split-step method) on the GPU. My goal was to modify [ybeltukov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4678/ybeltukov)'s code to get a 1D FFT of a 2D array (batch mode of `cuFFT`). I am rather a beginner in C and CUDA and I'm looking for some help.

I use Mathematica 10 under Win8.1 with the system installation of CUDA 5.0 and VS 2012. The GPU is a Quadro K600. I checked the installation with some basic compilation examples. Everything seems ok (`CUDAQ[]`, `CUDACCompiler` etc).

I encounter two troubles:

- the `"CUDAArchitecture->"` option for `CreateLibrary` is not recognized. It seems that my GPU supports 3.0. I tried `"CUDAArchitecture"->"sm_30"` and others (`->"30"` etc) but none worked
- I get the following compilation errors: "unresolved external symbol" for `cufftPLan1d`, `cufftExecC2C` and `cufftDestroy`. I tried to add `#include <cufft.h>` in the header of the C code but it failed. It seems that some library path is missing somewhere.

Compared to [ybeltukov's first post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47702/28113) the only modification I've done is to change  `"Libraries" -> FileNameJoin@{$CUDALinkLibraryPath, "libCUDALink_Single.so"}` into `"Libraries" -> FileNameJoin@{$CUDALinkLibraryPath, "libCUDALink_Single.lib"}` (there was no *.so in my `$CUDALinkLibraryPath`).

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your question. Actually `"CUDAArchitecture" -> "sm_30"` works, but `CreateLibrary` emits superfluous "Unknown option" error. The second question can be Win-specific (see also [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111925) question)

Comment: @Nicolas  Did you find a working solution to this?