# Can GPU (CUDA) speed up LinearSolve?

Tags: parallelization, cudalink, gpu

Is there a way to use GPU (CUDA) to speed up LinearSolve?

[GPU Cuda](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://tinyurl.com/6dazkd/reduction.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwiy0b-KpffQAhVFipAKHT4NCpgQFghCMAU&usg=AFQjCNFRk_wGHS-iYZMUPO98PirWVj52og&sig2=-cA-Od6WUNl-Gk3Ku5lpjA)

Comment: Sorry,  most likely not,  unless you code your own solution.

Comment: Formally, yes. You can find a proper CUDA library (or write your own) and call it directly from Mathematica ([ref](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47702)). However it is very difficult. Most likely, you will waste much more time than the possible speed up.

Comment: To add to what @ybeltukov says, a CPU implementation in C **might** be faster to implement than linking a CUDA library, but it might not be.

Comment: Extremely unlikely that you could rewrite `LinearSolve` to be faster without also providing more computational resources (e.g., GPU). It is pretty much a direct call to the MKL, which is about as optimized as it's possible for any software to be.

Comment: Like the other said, using the inbuilt LinearSolve functionality - no. Writing your own - yes - on the condition that what you're solving is extremely large and most of it is embarrassingly parallel. As @blochwave said, it might be faster depending on what you're solving.